# IBM Thinkpad running XP/SP2 hangs due to explorer.exe issue (I think)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, freeze

I have an IBM Thinkpad running XP w/ SP2 and recently it has started to hang when I open a folder or do anything related to explorer.exe (runs fine in safe mode though).  Has anyone faced similar issues? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this kind of thing happen with a bad Explorer shell extension. Have you installed anything recently that added to the file or folder context menus in Explorer?  For instance, antivirus software will often add a 'scan this file with blahblah' to the Explorer file context menu.  ShellExView from Nirsoft can be helpful in diagnosing this - it allows you to selectively disable/enable shell extensions.  Download from http://www.nirsoft.net/.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with one of my laptops.  Going into the task manager and killing the explorer.exe process and restarting it seems to resolve it for the short term, but you are probably looking at re-install of Windows as the real fix.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing windows updates to see if it fixes the issue.

If that doesnt work I suggest then doing a windows repair.